# How to get HTML element text with tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I get selected text with their HTML tag using `window.getSelection()`.

`window.getSelection()` only gives text like this **HELLO** But I want the text with HTML tag like this `<b>Hello</b>`

Answer (score 1):

```
let html;
let sel = window.getSelection();
if (sel.rangeCount) {
    var container = document.createElement("div");

    for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
        container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
    }

    html = container;
}
```